# Updating a string variable from within nested for loop in Scala

Tags: string, scala, nested-loops

I have a Dataframe which I am trying converting to html table syntax as a string in Scala:

**sample_df:**
which is of type DataFrame = Dataset[Row]

```
|Name|Country|Occupation|Years_Experience|
|Bob |USA    | Engineer |  5             |
|John|CANADA | Sales    |  3             |
```

I already have the html headers converted however need to have the html rows and values in a string variable as below
**html_string:**

```
<tr>
      <td>Bob</td>
      <td>USA</td>
      <td>Engineer</td>
      <td>5</td>
</tr>
<tr>
      <td>John</td>
      <td>CANADA</td>
      <td>Sales</td>
      <td>3</td>
</tr>
```

However when I try nested loop method below, the html_string variable is not being updated to what I am expecting above. It results in a blank. What am I doing wrong?

**Code Attempt:**

```
  var html_string = """"""

  for (i <- sample_df) {
    html_string = html_string + "<tr>"
    for (g <- i.toSeq)  {
      html_string = html_string + "<td>" + g + "</td>"
    }
    html_string = html_string + "</tr>"
  }
  println(html_string)
```

Thanks!

Comment: what type is `sample_df`?

Comment: @Dima, the type is type DataFrame = Dataset[Row]

Comment: seems like spark is a wrong tool for this. Just do it as a vanilla scala program

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what you mean by "dataframe" in this context (you can't iterate spark dataframes like this), but assuming you are talking about a normal sequence, this [works for me](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/498jNQHJTnmaOlGlPy7wzA).

Having said that, this is a very bad way of doing this in scala. The basic rule of thumb when writing scala code is *never use mutable variables* unless. you know *exactly* why you *must* in a specific case (which is extremely rare).

```
   val html_string = df
     .map { _.mkString("<td>", "</td><td>", "</td>" }
     .mkString("<tr>", "</tr><tr>",  "</tr>")
```

Comment: the dataframe type I have is "type DataFrame = Dataset[Row]"

Comment: to your point, I have converted the DataType to Sequence via "val html_string_new = html_string.collect().toSeq". and utilized the mkString option you have proposed. Thanks!